# Concept of a point particle in physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, continuum-mechanics, point-particles

How is mechanics, which deals with theoretical point particles, applied to real objects? For example, a force acting on a point particle is reasonable, but for an extended object, how is it natural to apply the concept of force? how can I even assume that the force acts at a point when there is no such thing for real objects? What's the definition of a point in space?

Comment: Where did you hear that mechanics only deals with point particles?

Comment: Extended bodies are defined in terms of point particles, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, and those point particles happen to be atoms or molecules, which have mass, and to which mechanics applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of continuous mechanics.

There are distributed forces over areas. For exemple: the normal force that acts on our feet when stand up is a integral of a pressure over the contact area.

Some forces like gravity are distributed over volumes, and called body forces.

As a result of normal and gravitational forces, all objects have an internal stress distribution. There is a tensor (stress tensor) and not a force associated with each point of bodies.

But, many times, the internal state of stress or the elastic deformation is not relevant, only the translational and/or rotational movement. In that cases, forces distributed over small areas can be modelled as point forces, and weight as concentrated in the COM.

Answer (score 1):

> How is mechanics, which deals with theoretical point particles,
> applied to real objects?

Mechanics doesn't only apply to "theoretical point particles". Real objects are composed of point particles, i.e., atoms and molecules.

> but for an extended object, how is it natural to apply the concept of
> force?

For an extended object, there is a center of mass (COM). To determine the behavior of an extended object when subjected to an external force, you need information on the line of action of the net force on an object relative to the COM of the object. If the line of action is through the COM, the force will cause translational acceleration of the object per Newton's 2nd law without rotation. If it is not through the COM, it will product both angular acceleration (due to torque) and translational acceleration.

> how can I even assume that the force acts at a point when there is no
> such thing for real objects?

There is a difference between a "point" and a "point particle". A "point" is a strictly geometrical concept. But a "point particle" is an object with mass that is concentrated to the extent that it can all be considered located at a point. An external force can only act on it if its line of action is through the point, which in the case of a point particle is the same as its COM, and that the particle can only undergo translational motion. This is the basis for the kinetic theory of gases. The gas molecules are considered to be point particles and their kinetic energy is strictly translational (no rotation).

> What's the definition of a point in space?

In classical Euclidean geometry, a point "is a primitive notion that models an exact location in space, and has no length, width, or thickness" (Wikipedia). When we use it as an adjective to describe a particle, it is a particle whose mass is considered concentrated at a point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to clarify: in mathematics 'primitive' means something similar to 'foundational', not 'outdated'.

Comment: @gs Yes. Synonyms include both "basic" and "archaic".

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Force acts upon point in space -> points in space are connected through rigid bodies

---

In Newtonian mechanics, a very small particle can be considered a point in space, e.g. a neutron.

Typically when we say a point in space, we assume such small particles, but with their volume $\lim V\to 0$.

When we are not talking about points in space, we talk about rigid bodies, which is a large set of particles with restraints for all *points in space* (such that they form a *large body*).

So if a force acts on *one* of the *points in space*, all particles will respond because of the rigid body *constraints* that bind them together.

Sometimes real objects are modeled as rigid bodies to do calculations, thus its natural to apply the concept of force.

Answer (score 0):

By applying Newton's laws to a system of particles (which may or may not exert forces on each other), it can be shown that the vector sum of the external forces acting on the system (no matter how they are distributed or applied) will determine the acceleration of the center of mass of the system in an inertial frame.  A similar analysis shows that the vector sum of the external torques (about any chosen point) will determine the rate of change of the total angular momentum about that point.